# Swift : println() doesn't show anything into "View Device Logs" in "Devices" tab

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am developing the application into which I need to get devicetoken when app is running with AdHoc profile.
Because I am not able to debug with AdHoc profile. I need to see log into which I print device token with println().
But, I doesn't show anything into it.

Comment: what is your swift version

Comment: use Developer certificate and run on your devices and get device token. @girish_pro

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, I got solution for it.
We can also user NSLog() into swift code. so, where we want to print log there you use NSLog() function.
Example ,

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        var deviceTokenOrigin = deviceToken.description.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "<>"))
        var deviceTokenFiltered = deviceTokenOrigin.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
        self.deviceTocken = deviceTokenFiltered
        NSLog("DeviceToken : %@", deviceTokenFiltered)
    }
```